# TableView not updating on new Information from Threads

Tags: multithreading, javafx, tableview

I made a small working example program for the problem i have. Please bare in mind that my real program is more complex and all those classes are needed, even if it looks overdimensioned in this small sample

Main Class :

```
public class PingTest extends Application {

private static final ArrayList<PingThread> THREADS = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    TableView<Map.Entry<String, Ping>> tblPing = new TableView();
    TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> colName = new TableColumn("Name");
    TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> colTime = new TableColumn("Time");
    TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> colDifference = new TableColumn("Difference");

    colName.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey()));
    colTime.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(p.getValue().getValue().getTime())));
    colDifference.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Ping>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(p.getValue().getValue().getDifference())));

    ObservableList<Map.Entry<String, Ping>> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Pings.getPings().entrySet());
    tblPing.setItems(items);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 750);

    // Align to pane
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tblPing, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tblPing, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tblPing, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tblPing, 0.0);

    tblPing.getColumns().addAll(colName, colTime, colDifference);
    root.getChildren().add(tblPing);

    // Setting primary Stage
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        THREADS.forEach(t -> t.interrupt());
    });
    primaryStage.setTitle("Ping List");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Some examples
    String[] servers = {"www.google.com", "www.bing.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.stackoverflow.com"};

    // Start Threads
    for (String server : servers) {
        PingThread pingThread = new PingThread(server);
        pingThread.start();
        THREADS.add(pingThread);
    }
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Helper Class

```
public class Ping {

private int difference;
private int time;
private final String url;

public Ping(String url,int time) {
    this.url = url;
    this.time = time;
    difference = 0;
}

public int getDifference() {
    return difference;
}

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(int time) {
    difference = time - this.time;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

}
```

Threads

```
public class PingThread extends Thread {

private final String SERVER;
private int ping = 0;

public PingThread(String server) {
    SERVER = server;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            // Ping, update then sleep
            ping();
            Pings.update(SERVER, ping);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Used to end thread
    }
}

public void ping() {
    try {
        // Sendinging request
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER);
        long tm = System.nanoTime();
        Socket so = new Socket(host, 80);
        so.close();
        ping =(int)( (System.nanoTime() - tm) / 1000000L);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}
```

}

Data Container

```
public class Pings {

private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,Ping> PINGS=  new ConcurrentHashMap();

public static synchronized void update(String server, int time) {
    if (PINGS.containsKey(server)) {
        PINGS.get(server).setTime(time);
    } else {
        PINGS.put(server, new Ping(server,time));
    }
}
public static synchronized ConcurrentHashMap<String,Ping> getPings(){
    return PINGS;
}
}
```

The GUI Table is not updating to new values, in my bigger implementation as in this small example. What am i doing wrong with binding the Values to the TableView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this code.

The most immediate is that calling

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList(Pings.getPings().entrySet());
```

creates a new observable list and adds everything in `Pings.getPings().entrySet()` to it. But subsequently modifying the set that was used to construct it will not modify the observable list, so the table will not change. You need to store the observable list in the model (`Pings`) and update it directly.

You also need to do the update on the FX Application Thread, and you will need to use JavaFX properties in your `Ping` class so the table can observe changes to those values.

So:

```
public class Ping {

    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper difference = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper time = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
    private final String url;

    public Ping(String url,int time) {
        this.url = url;
        setTime(time);
        difference.set(0);
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty differenceProperty() {
        return difference.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public final int getDifference() {
        return differenceProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty timeProperty() {
        return time ;
    }

    public final int getTime() {
        return timeProperty().get();
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        difference.set(time - getTime());
        this.time.set(time);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

The data has to be changed on the FX Application Thread, so your data container may as well be single-threaded:

```
public class Pings {

    private static final Map<String,Ping> PINGS=  new HashMap<>();
    private static final ObservableList<Ping> pingList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void update(String server, int time) {
        if (PINGS.containsKey(server)) {
            PINGS.get(server).setTime(time);
        } else {
            Ping ping = new Ping(server, time);
            pingList.add(ping);
            PINGS.put(server, ping);
        }
    }
    public static ObservableList<Ping> getPings(){
        return pingList;
    }

}
```

Now the threads do:

```
public class PingThread extends Thread {

    private final String SERVER;

    public PingThread(String server) {
        SERVER = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // Ping, update then sleep
                final int ping = ping();
                // again, not exactly sure how you want to handle exceptions...
                if (ping >= 0) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> Pings.update(SERVER, ping));
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Used to end thread
        }
    }

    public int ping() {
        try {
            // Sendinging request
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER);
            long tm = System.nanoTime();
            Socket so = new Socket(host, 80);
            so.close();
            return (int)( (System.nanoTime() - tm) / 1000000L);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return -1 ; // or handle exception?
        }

    }

}
```

And finally set the table up as:

```
TableView<Ping> tblPing = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Ping, String> colName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
TableColumn<Ping, Number> colTime = new TableColumn<>("Time");
TableColumn<Ping, Number> colDifference = new TableColumn<>("Difference");

colName.setCellValueFactory(p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue()));
colTime.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().timeProperty());
colDifference.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().differenceProperty());

tblPing.getColumns().addAll(colName, colTime, colDifference);

tblPing.setItems(Pings.getPings());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for yourt comprehensive explanation